# Excel Lookup Returning Date Values

Tags: excel, lookup

I have two sheets in my excel file: [main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glT5f.png) and [gender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJV5k.png).

The formula I use in main is `=LOOKUP(E2,gender!A2:B3)` which is `lookup array`.

But I've tried with `lookup vector` `=LOOKUP(E2,gender!A2:A3,gender!B2:B3)`.

The problem is I'm getting the date values as you can see in [main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glT5f.png). When I change 0 and 1 in gender sheet to other text values, they come up in main sheet.

How can I solve this problem? Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select F column in the main tab and set its cell format to General or Number.